# Plotting time series ggplot month-year, xaxis only show month with value?

Tags: r, date, plot, ggplot2, time-series

I have a 8 year time series data. I am able to plot my data but I want the x axis only to show the month which I have data for.

[image: my figure]

My problem here is that my x axis shows january but I have data only for june, july and august for each year.

I would also like to add vertical line to separate each year..

Here is how my script looks like so far:

```
ggplot(data=CMRB, aes(x=D, y=Densite, group = habitat)) + geom_line() + scale_x_date(date_labels ="%b%Y")+ geom_point( aes(shape=habitat),size=4, fill="white")
```

And my data looks like:

```
  Annee Grille Periode   Densite        SE Methode espece notes notes_2
82  2004    LG1     PP2 1.8888330 0.3990163    secr   brun            NA
83  2004    LG1     PP3 3.8880450 0.7570719    secr   brun            NA
84  2004    LG1     PP4 3.3281370 0.5573953    secr   brun            NA
85  2005    LG1     PP1 0.2367488        NA    secr   brun  mnka      NA
86  2005    LG1     PP2 0.4791649 0.2105729    secr   brun            NA
87  2005    LG1     PP3 0.1597214 0.1302571    secr   brun            NA
   habitat Mois      Date          D
82   humid   07 07/1/2004 2004-07-01
83   humid   08 08/1/2004 2004-08-01
84   humid   08 08/1/2004 2004-08-01
85   humid   06 06/1/2005 2005-06-01
86   humid   07 07/1/2005 2005-07-01
87   humid   08 08/1/2005 2005-08-01
>
```

D is a column I have created to tranform Date(which is a character) into a date format.

Does somebody knows how to do that ? If possible I would also like the month without data to take less space into the graph to leave more space to see the data from june to august...

Cheers

Nico

Comment: I'm not saying what you are doing is incorrect, but dygraphs is specifically designed for plotting time series data. Are you adamant on using ggplot2 for this?

Comment: Just set the `breaks` argument of `scale_x_date`.

Comment: Specifically, something like `scale_x_date(date_labels ="%b%Y", breaks = unique(CMRB$D))`

Comment: @alistaire

Perhaps the only issue is that unique(CMRB$D) will provide too many dates on the plot's x-axis?

Comment: ...so index it: `unique(CMRB$D)[seq(1, length(unique(CMRB$D), by = 2)]`

Comment: didnt think you can subset by indexing using seq, thats a nice trick.

Comment: I didn't know about the dygraphs, I'll try that ! thanks ! 
to alistaire, the break argument works for the axe but the problem is that the data still are aggregate on the graph..

Comment: it kinda work for the axis but still overlapps, I might just add the axis manually and only add the first letter of the months j a j per example, nice tricks with seq btw

Comment: Honestly, for the graph shown, I'd just leave the breaks where they are, and label with just the year. Unless you're going to make a really wide version, that's the easiest to interpret. It's probably also what ggplot gives you by default, as it happens.

Comment: I guess I wanted to be more precise by I think you are right only the year matter ... But would you know how to add a vertical line to separate each year it would make the graph more clear ?

Comment: use something like `+geom_vline(xintercept %in% c(seq(2000, 2016, 1))` 

or 

`+geom_vline(xintercept = 2000:2016)` 
 in addition your ggplot code.

Here's a whole document dedicated towards this: 

http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_vline.html


If you want to have a vertical line in dygraphs, use `dyEvent`, read the syntax on the link provided in the answer I've given below.

Comment: dosen't seem to work with geom_vline because my x axis is a Date

Comment: youve got to insert a date then there instead of a number, i think it has to be of the same type and scale as your x-axis values.

Answer (score 1):

This should convert into a date column.

```
CMRB <- as.Date(CMRB$D, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

If you want to plot time-series data, I suggest using `dygraphs`

For example,

```
library(dygraphs)

library(xts)

ts_object <- as.xts(CMRB$Densite, CMRB$D)

dygraph(ts_object)
```

Here's the holy grail of websites to guide you through dygraphs.

https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/